# Extjs window doesnt show elements well in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs

I have this code

```
 var main_container = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container',
 {
     xtype: 'container',
     id: "id_container",
     anchor: '100%',
     layout:'column',
     items:[
        column_1,
        column_2,
        column_3
     ]
})
```

And when I resize the container the rightmost column in some cases disapears. When I resize again in some cases the rightmost column appears again. This happens only in IE.

What could be causing this? Any idea would be helpful.

Here is the structure of the rightmost column

```
  var column_3 = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container',
  {
    columnWidth: .33,
    layout: 'anchor',
    id: 'column_3',
    items:[
        grid_1,
        grid_2
    ]
  })
```

There are 3 columns and i want them to be 33 percent wide

And the main container is oppened upon pressing ext js menu button.
And the main container is placed in ext js window.

This is my problem

```
 <div class="x-container x-column x-container-default" id="column_roles" role="presentation" style="width: 400px;">
       <DIV style="WIDTH: 413px; HEIGHT: 45%" id=grid_1 class="x-panel  x-grid x-property-grid x-panel-default x-with-col-lines x-panel-with-col-lines x-panel-default-with-col-lines x-masked-relative x-masked" role=presentation aria-labelledby=component-1234>...</div>

        <DIV style="WIDTH: 413px; HEIGHT: 45%" id=grid_2 class="x-panel  x-grid x-property-grid x-panel-default x-with-col-lines x-panel-with-col-lines x-panel-default-with-col-lines x-masked-relative x-masked" role=presentation aria-labelledby=component-1237> ... </div>
 </div>
```

you can see clearly that inner divs are wider than the one that contains them. Why IE generates badly? This doesnt happen in Chrome and FF.

Comment: This question is rather vague. How are the columns constructed? Is the container rendered to an element, placed inside another container? What version of Ext4?

Comment: Yes, extjs 4. Columns are also of type Ext.container.Container

Comment: My point is, why make it a guessing game? Post an example that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this happens only in IE, did you consider to discard IE as a browser? Jokes aside, if it works in any browser except IE maybe could be a bug or you have to do something special only for IE.

For example, this works for me:

```
Ext.onReady (function () {
    Ext.create ('Ext.window.Window', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody () ,
        title: 'Win' ,
        width: 500 ,
        height: 100 ,
        layout: 'anchor' ,
        resizable: true ,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'container' ,
            anchor: '100%' ,
            layout: 'column' ,
            defaults: {
                layout: 'anchor'
            } ,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'container' ,
                columnWidth: .33 ,
                defaults: {
                    xtype: 'textfield' ,
                    anchor: '100%'
                } ,
                items: [{
                    fieldLabel: 'name'
                } , {
                    fieldLabel: 'surname'
                }]
            } , {
                xtype: 'container' ,
                columnWidth: .33 ,
                defaults: {
                    xtype: 'textfield' ,
                    anchor: '100%'
                } ,
                items: [{
                    fieldLabel: 'age'
                } , {
                    fieldLabel: 'place'
                }]
            } , {
                xtype: 'container' ,
                columnWidth: .33 ,
                defaults: {
                    xtype: 'textfield' ,
                    anchor: '100%'
                } ,
                items: [{
                    fieldLabel: 'nickname'
                } , {
                    fieldLabel: 'whatever'
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }).show();
});
```

When you resize the window, each column is resized too and no one disappears.

Ciao

Wilk

Comment: I do the same thing as you but the difference is I create the columns before I create the main container. Could there be some problem with the order of creation?

Comment: I tried your tests but it works the same. Now I can't test IE 'cause I'm working on a Linux machine and I'm too lazy to emulate it. However, if it works for you on any browser, ask on Sencha Forum if it's a bug or not. Maybe, on IE, column layout is handled in a different way.... I don't know, sorry.

Comment: Ok. I ispected the main container in IE9 trough the HTML code and found that the width of the third column is smaller for 10-13 pixels than the component that I put in the column container. What is causing this?

Comment: This happens only in IE. FF anc Chrome process the widths and percents just fine.